# How to load data on scroll in select2 dropdown without using pagination?

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2

I have more than 1000 rows and it is taking much time in taking AJAX response and loading data in dropdwon.
I am  using below code .

```
function fillperson() {       

$.ajax({
   // delay: 250 ,
    url: Url,
    type: "GET",
    minimumInputLength:0,
    data: { isGetAll: false, Id1: 0, ID2:0},
    complete: function (data) {
        var ele = document.getElementById('ddlperson');
        ele.innerHTML = '';
        var persondata = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
        ele.innerHTML = '<option value="' + -1 + '">Select Person</option>';
        ele.innerHTML += '<option value="' + 0 + '">ALL Person</option>';
        var totaldata = persondata.length;
        var i = 0;            

            for ( i ; i < data.length; i++) {
                ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML +
                    '<option value="' + data[i]['Id'] + '">' +data[i]['name'] + '(' + data[i]['code'] + ')' + '</option>';                  
            }
            $('#ddperson').select2();

    },       
});
```

}

Comment: I got the  solution just cleared dd before any data binding and updated dropdown after getting every 200 data in loop.I don't know whether its right way or not.But It's working in my code perfectly.

Comment: Can anybody provide a  solution for How to load data on scroll in  nice select dropdown without using pagination in ajax call?As I have 8000 options in Dropdown and that is why dropdown is taking time in loading this much options.I need to update existing valye while editing details.So, I cannot use Jquery auto complete pulgin.